# Are there examples of SEXP declarations in Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

I read in Hadley Wickham's book that RObjects should be declared as S-expressions (SEXP) in R's C API:

```
SEXP x( SEXP a, SEXP b {
}
```

In Rcpp, however, it seems this necessity is over. In other words, functions should be declared with some defined datatype, for example:

```
NumericVector x(NumericVector a, NumericVector b) {
 }
```

Are there examples where SEXP declarations are still useful in Rcpp's context?

Answer (score 3):

Yes *of course* as *everything* gets translated to/from `SEXP`.  In some cases we opt to keep a `SEXP`.

A 'classic' example is the [run-time switching on type](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-wrap-and-recurse/) (where it shows a `List` but you can do the same with a single `SEXP`).  Other examples are the `as<>` and `wrap()` converters.

And ... of course code where users chose to keep a `SEXP`. You can search at the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) for more examples, and/or of course also search here among the almost 2000 questions for Rcpp.

Comment: Here is a great post from the Rcpp Gallery that illustrates your point further: [Cleaner Generic Functions with RCPP_RETURN Macros](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-return-macros/)